# Are the following properties of summation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**In our "textbook" it asks if the following are properties of summations:**

1. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (c \cdot a_{n}) = c \cdot \displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (a_{n})$
2. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (a_{n} \pm b_{n}) = (\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} a_{n}) \pm (\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} b_{n})$
3. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (a_{n} \cdot b_{n}) = (\sum_{n=j}^{k} a_{n}) \cdot (\sum_{n=j}^{k} b_{n})$
4. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} a_{n}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} b_{n}}$
5. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{k} a_{n} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} a_{n-1}$
6. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{k} c = ck$
7. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} c = ck$

---

**I know that 1 & 2 are true:**

1. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (c \cdot a_{n}) = c \cdot \displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (a_{n})$
2. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (a_{n} \pm b_{n}) = (\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} a_{n}) \pm (\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} b_{n})$

---

**I also know that 3 & 4 are not true:**

1. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} (a_{n} \cdot b_{n}) \ne (\sum_{n=j}^{k} a_{n}) \cdot (\sum_{n=j}^{k} b_{n})$
2. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} \ne \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} a_{n}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=j}^{k} b_{n}}$

---

I'm not sure if 5 & 6 & 7 are true, though. Are they true, and why or why not?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hint: choose a small value like $k=4$ and write out both sides of the (potential) identities. Are they equal without further assumptions? Does this help you understand the general case where $k$ can be arbitrarily large?

Comment: 6 and 7 cannot both be true unless $c=0$

Answer (score 1):

$(5)$ is true, and it's easy to see why: just list out the terms individually.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^k a_n &= a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k \\
\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} a_{n-1} &= a_{1-1} + a_{2-1} + a_{3-1} + \cdots + a_{k+1-1} \\
&= a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots a_k
\end{align*}$$

If you're not convinced, try a particular small value of $k$ you can easily handle, like $k=5$.

---

$(6)$ is not true in full generality, but $(7)$ is. The *true* identity is

$$\sum_{n=1}^k c = ck$$

(Notice we start at $n=1$, not $n=0$.) This is like the other summations, but the term is constant and does not depend on $n$. Hence, you're sort of plugging in a different $n$ each time into $a_n$, but always just getting $c$ out. Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^k c = \underbrace{c+c+c+\cdots+c}_{\text{$k$ times}} = kc$$

Of course, then

$$\sum_{n=0}^k c = (k+1)c \ne kc$$

(unless $c=0$). In general, a summation $\sum_{n=j}^k a_n$ will have $k-j+1$ terms.